# Is there a name for this hash function?

Tags: c, hash

I have used the [Elk Scheme interpreter](http://sam.zoy.org/elk/) for quite a while and browse its source code sometimes.

I noticed that it contains the following hash function in symbol.c:

```
int Hash (char const *str, unsigned int len) {
    register int h;
    register char const *p, *ep;

    h = 5 * len;
    if (len > 5)
        len = 5;
    for (p = str, ep = p+len; p < ep; ++p)
        h = (h << 2) ^ *p;
    return h & 017777777777;
}
```

There is nothing in the source code that describes the function.

Is there a name for this hash function?
Is the hashing scheme documented somewhere?

Comment: That thing is old. I wonder if there's some point where the hash in scheme is visible in scheme code, and they had to keep the old hash.

Comment: @Joshua, it is used only once in the code base: `h = Hash (str, len) % OBARRAY_SIZE;` where `h` is of type `int`. `h` is used as an index to an array.

Comment: Looks like it's basically a [FNV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) algorithm with different constants. Odd how it only looks at the first 5 characters...

Comment: Unfortunately, the Subversion commit log doesn't contain a useful explanatory message, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it's essentially the same algorithm as the classic [Fowler-Noll-Vo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) hash, but instead of using a specially chosen prime number for the hash's multiplier, it uses `4` (Left shifting a number by 2 is the same as multiplying by 4). The initial seed value of the hash is different too; `5 * len` instead of a constant value.

It only hashes up to the first five characters of the string, which is an odd choice that I'm sure the author had some good reason for.

The last line `return h & 017777777777;` is interesting, too. That octal constant is, assuming a typical 32 bit 2's compliment `int`, `INT_MAX`. It's the sort of thing you'd see if calculating a 64 bit hash but returning only the low 32 bits, but on a 32 bit type it's a no-op. Maybe the author was paranoid about portability to systems with a bigger int type? But if it's only used in that one spot where the returned hash value is taken modulo an array length, why bother? Or maybe `h` was intended to be an `unsigned int` but they didn't want to use the full range of that type (Or make sure it was never negative when turned into a signed value)?

Comment: The `return h & 017777777777;` makes sense since the interpreter had been ported to many hardware platforms. It's possible one or more of them used 64 bits for `int`. I certainly appreciate the forethought.

Comment: FNV without a prime is no FNV, not that I would expect people to know that. If the caller doesn't do mod prime, this has bad rehash characteristics.